# Docker container service getting 'conection refused' when trying to call a REST API on another container even on the same custom bridge network

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I got two spring-boot services and a Postgres DB's integration which Service 1 calls(HTTP) service 2 and service 2 integrate with Postgres and each service is running on a container. The problem is when service 1 calls service 2, it receives a connection refused and I have no clue why once all services seem to be on the same network (that's not a default bridge network. It works when I ping container 2 from container one, but when curl service 2 Endpoint, I got the error 'can't resolve the hostname'. Any help would be very welcome cause I'm tired of docker!

**Docker-compose**

```yaml
version: '3.7'
networks:
  valkyre-network:
    driver: bridge
services:
  db:
    image: 'postgres:latest'
    container_name: db
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    volumes:
      - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    expose:
      - 5432
    networks:
      - valkyre-network
  valreim-player-register:
    image: 'reiiissamuel/valreim-player-register:latest'
    build:
      context: .
    container_name: valreim-player-register
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/postgres
      - DATABASE_USERNAME=postgres
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD=postgres
      - FTP_REMOTE_WL_PATH=/files/valheim/valheim/server/BepInEx/config/aac_whitelistedDLLs.txt
      - FTP_REMOTE_HOST=http://104.248.238.7:49153
      - FTP_REMOTE_HOST_PORT:2022
      - FTP_REMOTE_HOST_USER:reiiissamuel
      - FTP_REMOTE_HOST_PASSWORD:Sbmvflrfjs23
    ports:
      - "8087:8087"
    expose:
      - 8087
    networks:
      - valkyre-network
  valkyre-bot:
    container_name: valkyre-bot
    build:
      context: .
    image: 'reiiissamuel/valkyre:latest'
    depends_on:
      - valreim-player-register
    environment:
      - REGISTER_API_URL=http://valreim-player-register:8087/register/players
    networks:
      - valkyre-network
```

**Docker network inspect**

```sh
$ docker network inspect valkyre_valkyre-network
[
    {
        "Name": "valkyre_valkyre-network",
        "Id": "862793d31abb81b777a9dd363fdf40cf1f867779a81857ea8b814d308f7b8903",
        "Created": "2022-02-15T05:51:30.9692795Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.30.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.30.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": true,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "452659d8b9c4523fe55dcce2caeef374cc2838f88d2fb4502e90e7adfa71d2bd": {
                "Name": "db",
                "EndpointID": "5c60f27249b478a3e3b388f97f729d8e6363139a179cdbfa179341adfa5420fd",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:1e:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.30.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "9bd52710f8239182fe083397a6b022bd774f8982efa5a0495849853a67eaa63d": {
                "Name": "valreim-player-register",
                "EndpointID": "e205076c01be599aab1c6537e0d2f80d2704d44882bbe190b7266f1c546d7fab",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:1e:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.30.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "ac326acd43477f72c1e288ff7fd91d8cb0f2c26472071a3daa81dd82b8ccf886": {
                "Name": "valkyre-bot",
                "EndpointID": "bd33dded4fb9d2bb05a89073c8acc3981588c9362799f5f3568f3d4831333274",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:1e:00:04",
                "IPv4Address": "172.30.0.4/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.network": "valkyre-network",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "valkyre",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "1.29.2"
        }
    }
]
```

**Successfull ping from service 1 to service 2**

```sh
D:\java-projects\valkyre>docker container exec -it valkyre-bot ping valreim-player-register -p 8087
PATTERN: 0x8087
PING valreim-player-register (172.29.0.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from valreim-player-register.valkyre_valkyre-network (172.29.0.3): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.067 ms
...
--- valreim-player-register ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 10 received, 0% packet loss, time 9226ms
```

**Unsuccessfully curl endpoint service 2 from service 1**

```
# curl -v -L http://valreim-player-register:8087/register/players/steamid/111
*   Trying 172.30.0.3:8087...
* connect to 172.30.0.3 port 8087 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to valreim-player-register port 8087: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to valreim-player-register port 8087: Connection refused
```

**Java service's 1 method where service 2 is call**
(Guess it wont be useful, but extra info never hurts)

```java
public void sendRegisterUser(PlayerReg player) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        logger.info("Cadastrando player na base...");
        String payload = player.toString();
        StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(payload,
                ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(PLAYER_REGISTER_API_URI);
        request.setEntity(entity);

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

        if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 201)
            throw new IOException(String.valueOf(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()));
    }
```

Comment: The first ping is from container to container, the second ping seems from local machine to container, that will not work by using the container name.

Comment: Ty man! I just forgot to use docker exec command, my bad! Question, updated. But even when I execute curl from the container I have no success.